# Applying a Style by code to a button

Tags: android, xml, button, styles

I´m coding a app where I have to show buttons for each Item from BD I get, so I created a fragment that contains a ScrollView and inside the Scroll a LinearLayout.

Also I´ve created my own style for the button (it has a "+" icon on the left):

```
<style name="myButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:drawableLeft">@drawable/ic_add_24dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    />
</style>
```

So in the code what I do is to create the button with the following in onCreateView:

mV = inflater.inflate(R.layout.this_fragment, container, false);

```
    LinearLayout scroll = (LinearLayout) mV.findViewById(R.id.linearScrollView);//linearScrollView is my LinearLayout 

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size();i++)
    {
        Button mButton = new Button(mV.getContext(), null, R.style.myButtonStyle);
        mButton.setText(list.get(i).getName());
        mButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

            }
        });
        scroll.addView(mButton);
    }
    return mV;
```

So when I try to test this in the phone, I get all my elements but the style seems to be missing, I have a element just with the text, I dont see the icon.

But if I add in the fragment view buttons using the style that I´ve created they look as I want!